# Подскажите пожалуйста насчет SharedPrederences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Изучаю как работает `SharedPreferences`, есть `TextView` в который выводится либо `TRUE` либо `FALSE` в зависимости от того что сохранено в настройках в `SwitchPreference`, но почему то в `TextView` всегда написано TRUE. Делал по [примеру](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/134-urok-71-preferences-kak-nastrojki-prilozhenija-preferenceactivity.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

TextView text;
Button btn;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = findViewById(R.id.tex);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent_1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Prefs.class);
            startActivity(intent_1);
        }
    });
     sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (sp.getBoolean("switch", false))
    {
        text.setText("FALSE");
    }
    if (sp.getBoolean("switch", true))
    {
        text.setText("TRUE");
    }

    super.onPostResume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала у вас не правильно написана логика проверки переменной.
 [`sp.getBoolean("switch", false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) - Первым параметром передается имя переменной, вторым значение по умолчанию. Должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
if (sp.getBoolean("switch", true)) {
   text.setText("TRUE");
} else {
   text.setText("FALSE");
}
```

Comment: а можно так :) `text.setText(String.valueOf(sp.getBoolean("switch", false)).toUpperCase());`

Comment: мне казалось что 1 параметр ключ, а второй его значение для проверки. Ну это многое объясняет, спасибо